# Code Not Running in Release Mode in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows

I have an issue in using visual studio 2013 with my windows phone. Whenever i use release mode for my windows phone application the app stops at the break point and Visual studio shows "Code Not Running". However, disabling the break point resolves the issue. But I want to debug my app for fixing the issues which i have in my app.

In Debug mode the application works perfectly at breakpoints whether it is managed only or native only using the emulator. But it stops the application when i try to debug it in the release mode using my device. I think i'm missing some settings for the release mode of my application for debugging using my windows phone.

P.S The break point cannot currently be hit while i'm debugging Managed Only code.

Answer (score 0):

Release mode requires that the *.pdb files, *which allow debugging*, need to be with the executable. Usually a publish in release mode doesn't publish the `pdb` debug files for obvious reasons. You can add the pdb files to release making it a defacto debug build, or simply (as I recommend) you debug the issue in debug mode and get it resolved.

I surmise you are running into *logical* bugs which a debugger may not catch per-se and why it happens in release mode only. You may need to comment out code or instances to track down the faulty behavior which you are trying to fix and divine a resolution from the removed code.

Comment: My fellow peer is debugging using the release mode but in visual studio 2012. I'm unable to debug in release mode using vs 2013. I think there is some setting for vs 2013.
Debugging in emulator is a temporary solution. I want a permanent solution for this.

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibZahid Ok, something similar happened to me when I installed Azure Web Services over a working emulator. It installed a secondary component which caused the emulator to fail. To resolve the issue I reinstalled (or repaired) the latest Visual Studio update.

Answer (score 0):

As OmegaMan already mentioned Release mode does not include Debug info and you should debug your App in debug mode.

However if you really need debug info do the following:

- Right click Project
- Properties
- Build
- Advanced
- Set Debug Info to full or pdb only

Comment: I can't comment your question yet so I'll do it here: So your problem only exists when you debug in release mode with your real device? Debugging the release works for the simulator?

Comment: I didnt tested debugging the release mode in simulator. I will check it out.